# Where can I “hide” easter eggs for students learning about Linux security?

Tags: linux, unix, user-education, defense

I feel like this isn't the best place to ask this (since there's no single right answer), but I can't think of a better place. If you have a better recommendation, could you please recommend it and I can move the question rather than just having it closed outright?

I'm teaching a class of high-school students about general Linux security. At a high level I want them to be able to take a given Linux server and know how to harden it against common security issues - e.g. closing old accounts, using a strong pw hashing algorithm, make sure no strange processes are running or run at boot. Their skill-level is a broad range, and I'm looking for ways to motivate them to use what we've been discussing (e.g. look at crontab; look at users and group configurations; look at open ports).

I have been given $200 to hold a competition to encourage them, and I thought maybe I could purchase a bunch of Amazon gift cards in $10 increments. The idea would be to "hide" the redemption codes in various places on our sandbox server for the kids to find. For example, I could store the passwords in plaintext, and have one of the example user accounts assigned a password of one of the codes. Or maybe I could set up a cron job to log one of the codes to a system log every 30 seconds.

What I'm looking for is places/methods to hide these codes such that someone looking to secure the server would stumble across them.

Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

I can think of a few ideas:

- put the codes inside a file running at boot, discoverable when the user run `strings` on it
- put the codes on suid scripts (you should never ever have suid scripts)
- put codes on world-writable binaries on /sbin
- put codes on world-readable config files somewhere
- put codes on tmp files
- put codes as a chain name on iptables

Things like that.

Comment: Another evil trick: unmount `/tmp`, write a file to the underlying file system (i.e. the `/tmp` directory in the root filesystem) and then re-mount `/tmp`. Can only be found by enumerating inodes or guessing the trick and unmounting it.

Comment: @Polynomial:  Wow.  Yes that's evil.  I think that's beyond our current skillset at this point.  Awesome though - thanks again!

Comment: @Polynomial if you have mount,  just mount an image that contains a setuid root backdoor.

Comment: @Rook The idea wasn't to exploit it, but rather to hide a file somewhere for a challenge.

Answer (score 3):

Setting up system to be hacked and judging the results is commonly known as a Capture The Flag (CTF).   There are a lot of open source CTFs out there,  [root-the-box](https://github.com/moloch--/RootTheBox) is a great CTF that focuses more on post-exploitation and has puzzles for neophytes.  There is also [Damn Vulnerable Linux](http://distrowatch.com/table.php?distribution=dvl),  which is an educational tool.

A more simplistic CTF would be to have Easter-eggs in the form of user accounts which could be obtained using the following attacks.  I chose the following three because I have seen them int he real world:

- [setuid backdoor](https://gist.github.com/dergachev/7916152) to obtain privileges as root or another user.  Or more complex variants such as [attacks using mount](http://lwn.net/Articles/465311/).
- Cracking the [shadow file or a htpasswd file with [john the

  ripper](http://www.openwall.com/john/doc/EXAMPLES.shtml).
- Reading a plaintext [password stored in ~/.bash_history](https://superuser.com/questions/736635/i-accidentally-typed-password-into-bash-command-line) file.

In a real world situation the above attacks would take place in post-exploitation.  Penetration testers and blackhats will use tools like [Metasploit's post exploitation modules](http://www.offensive-security.com/metasploit-unleashed/MSF_Post_Exploitation),  [Weevly](https://github.com/epinna/Weevely), and [Veil-Pillage](https://www.veil-framework.com/category/veil-pillage/) to help automate this process.